# Use logback config file not on classpath for spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback

I have a simple application with a simple `logback.xml` file, which I do not wish to put on the classpath.  I can guarantee that it will be present where the application is run from, though.

I tried `--logging.config=file:./logback.xml`, but spring does not seem to honor the setting.  What is the recommended way to achieve this?  Thanks!

Comment: You can use resource plugin and keep it wherever you want.

Comment: Sprinboot made it very easy to write logs to external files. Just change the path from whitin the application.properties file. See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38527175/spring-boot-no-log-file-written-logging-file-is-not-respected?noredirect=1#comment64554948_38527175

Comment: @Georgesvanhoutte:  I was trying to specify the location of the config file, not the output file.

Comment: Ok. Then you should override Spring Boot auto-configuration with explicit configuration like @PropertySource annotation;  See doc : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html

Answer (score 1):

It should be easy, as Logback has a feature for this purpose:

```
java -Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/config.xml ...
```

You can read more in the [logback documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#configFileProperty).