# Spring Boot - no log file written (logging.file is not respected)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback, slf4j

I use Spring Boot and want it to write log output to a file.

According to the docs, this is simply done by setting

```
logging.file=filename.log
```

While the console output works fine, `filename.log` is not created. Also, if I create the file manually, nothing is written to it. What do I miss?

Comment: Where did you put your `filename.log`?

Comment: Please show your : application.properties file

Comment: By default, Spring Boot configures logging via Logback (http://logback.qos.ch) to log to the console at INFO level. However, if you decide that you’d rather use Log4j or Log4j2, you’ll need to change your dependencies to include the appropriate starter for the logging implementation you want to use and to exclude Logback.

Comment: @AliDehghani I assumed the logfile will be created if it does not exist. However, I created the file manually in the directory where I start the application, but nothing is written to it. I also used `logging.path=/var/log` as in the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logging-file-output), but no log file is created there either.

Comment: @Georgesvanhoutte It looks like this: `logging.level.root=INFO logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO logging.file=logfile.log` However, in production I use the `--logging.file=logfile.log` as command line option in order to avoid submitting sensitive data to the VCS.

Comment: This won't be helpful probably.. but when I went back to the log folder, there was no file there. I created it in /var/log/spring and verified it's there, but then I went back and it was missing. Weird. When I recreated it, spring was logging into it.

Comment: Hope my answer and its parent one gives you more insights on the problem.

Comment: Use **logging.file.name** for 2.2+ instead. logging.file was deprecated in 2.2 and totally removed in 2.3, so you can no longer use logging.file in 2.3+.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I found a solution. I am not very happy with it since it still does not answer my original question why the `logging.file` property is not respected.

I created the `logback-spring.xml` from Georges' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38584210/6313877) in the same directory where `application.properties` resides. According to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html) Spring Boot will pick it up from there. Apparently, this does not happen in my case.

I need to additionally add `logging.config=classpath:logback-spring.xml` in order it is picked up by Spring. The relevant parts of my `application.properties` are now

```
logging.config=classpath:logback-spring.xml
logging.file=logs/logfile.log
```

(I created the `logs` directory manually.)

Comment: +1 : `logging.config` is needed in `application.properties` if somebody is trying to integrate spring batch admin UI with a Spring Boot batch job and have overridden `env-context.xml` from `spring-batch-admin-manager` project.

Comment: Has your project already included `logback.xml` in the resource folder?

Comment: `logging.file` is respected for sure, depends on the fact how you specify the path, file will be created there. As a sample, in my project I have following configuration of logging in the application.yml - `logging:`
  `file: logs/dictoro-livescore-api.log`
  `level: INFO` and it is creating log file in file system (I'm using Linux Ubuntu) in the folder `/logs`

Comment: This is not necessary: `logging.config=classpath:logback-spring.xml`. But it might be useful if you want to have different logback configs for different profiles (prod vs dev). Also you don't have to create the folder.

Comment: How do I create log files inside my spring boot project directory? I want to create separate files for error and info messages. I'm using spring boot v. 2.5
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 96):

Use `logging.file.name` instead of `logging.file`

In higher versions of `spring-boot-parent(from version 2.2.0)`, property logging.file is deprecated.

Comment: I have upgraded to the latest Springboot version and the log file was not created.
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It worked for me. I am using 2.3.1 version. Thanks a lot. It was really helpful.

Comment: link to documentation (choose your Spring Boot version): https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/

Answer (score 24):

In my case, I used below, in the application property file.

> `logging.file`

Instead, I need to use the below one:

> `logging.file.name`

Since then, I could be able to get the logs into the directed path file.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem.  It's more than likely due to file permissions on the file system.  I had the application folder owned by root, but ./logs owned by the process owner.  As such, the following didn't work:

```
logging.file=my.log
```

but this did

```
logging.file=/opt/myapp/logs/my.log
```

Comment: As indicated by Vivek below, logging.file is now deprecated so unless you're using an older version of Spring, please follow that guidance instead of mine which is now out of date.

Answer (score 8):

**Spring Boot: Version 2.4.3**

Either one of them should be used in `application.properties` file:  `logging.file.name` or `logging.file.path`

For example:

```
logging.file.name=logs/myapp.log
logging.file.path=logs
```

You don't have to create `logs` directory. It will be created automatically in class path.

To see other deprecated properties, read this class file `~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.4.3/spring-boot-2.4.3.jar!/org/springframework/boot/logging/LoggingSystemProperties.class`

Comment: did not work for me `logging.file.path=../tmp`

Answer (score 6):

Here is how i managed to write output to a local file file. 
To disable console logging and write output only to a file you need a custom **logback-spring.xml** *( call it **logback-spring.xml** so you ll take advantage of the templating features (date formatting etc..) provided by Boot)* that imports **file-appender.xml** instead of console-appender.xml. In order to achieve this, you must paste this code below into your logback-spring.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

You also need to add the following to your application.properties:

```
logging.file=myapplication.log
```

Notice that this log file **myapplication.log** will be generated by springboot.

This is how my application structure tree looks like:

[image]

If you want to have more fun, you can locate the base.xml in your maven dependencies like this:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but this does not do the trick for me, either. I changed my `application.properties` such that the only logging-related line is `logging.file=logfile.log`. This disables console logging. Yet, no logfile is written. (Yes, I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.6 and Yes, the logback config file resides under `resources`).

Comment: did you refresh your app after running it ?

Comment: you can download my code and test it. : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_EVyl90ivXwQ3NpVHllVWpQZmM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: See my answer below: `logging.config=classpath:logback-spring.xml` did the trick.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know whether this would help you but I am also using Logback in my `Spring-Boot` project and the structure is as below

[image]

**File:** logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="logback.xsd">

    <property resource="\application.properties"/>

    <appender name="FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${app.logPathPrefix}/myproject.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${app.logPathPrefix}/myproject.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%level] [%thread] [%logger:%line] %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%level] [%thread] [%logger:%line] %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>


    <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="com.mycompany" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="DEBUG" />


    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

**File:** application.properties

```
app.logPathPrefix=/var/log/myproject
```

Answer (score 5):

Check the version of the Springboot parent.

if it is 2.3.x+ then the property should be logging.file.name=yourapplog.log

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Maven add the dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Now you have to specify a file that is called 'log4j.properties' which you have to put in the specific directory : ' src/main/resources/log4j.properties '

Here is how the file should look for example :

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout
log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.received=TRACE

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# log4j.appender.springlog.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.springlog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.springlog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=D:/example/filename.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Now import these :

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

Declare a logger variable like this :

```
final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TheClassYourIn.class);
```

And use it in the class like this :

```
logger.info("Well hello world then ");
```

This way it works for me. I hope that this answer will help you . Good luck !

PS: log4j.appender.file.File='directory' is how you specify where the logs to be stored. If you don't specify a directory and just leave it as filename.log this file will be automaticly created in the project dir.

Comment: This is a valid answer in my opinion. Sometimes the answer may not work because of the user environment or the package the the user suppose to log isn't specified. I am giving a up vote for this.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed example. However, I will use logback since it comes with Spring Boot.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to place log file in specific directory like D drive then below changes can be done in spring boot project

1.Create **logback-spring.xml** configuration file and mention the package name of which you want to create logs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
    
        <logger name="com.example.demo" 
        level="DEBUG" >
           
        </logger>
</configuration>
```

2.Also make below addition in **application.properties** file

```
logging.config=classpath:logback-spring.xml
logging.file.name=F:/Springbootlogs/filename.log
```

Note: The mentioned changes are for version 2.4.3

Answer (score 1):

I just used the Spring-boot provided logging mechanism. I wrote below in my 'logback.xml' file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file- appender.xml" />
<root level="INFO">
<appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

I put the both application.properties and logback.xml file under same package 'src/main/resources'.
In application.properties file just added one parameter :

```
logging.file = xyz.log
```

It worked perfectly fine for me.

Comment: There is a typo in the include of the file-appender.xml, but I cannot edit it because it's less than 6 characters

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I added a file "logback.xml" in one of my sub module by mistake which caused this issue, remove it and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply. It seems spring's logger reads the property from its own classpath.***[Due to precedence,](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config)*** it's not respecting the properties supplied.

#### Some tricks to get around:

1. In main class set the property variable using `springApplication.setDefaultProperties(properties);` like this

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(MainClass.class);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("logging.file", logDirectory);
        springApplication.setDefaultProperties(properties);
        springApplication.run(args);
    }
```

2. Pass the property as JVM parameter `-Dlogging.file=/location/output.log`.

Both of the above are not the best ones as in order to define other logging properties they also should follow the same way.

#### Solution

Define a property file and put all you logging configurations in that and specify the file in `-Dspring.config.location`. This is a derivation of [my other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54519104/6663095) and [this is how I resolved that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54722355/6663095). check that out in order to know other solutions that I've tried and their challenges.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue in windows operating system . I just changed -> logging.file to logging.file.name=D:/customer_projects/flight_reservation_system/logs/reservation.log

Note: Spring-boot version which i used is 2.4.1

in windows operating system when you copy file path from file explorer you will get file path like D:\customer_projects\flight_reservation_system\logs\flight_reservation.log

Above file path will not work. so you need to change file path like D:/customer_projects/flight_reservation_system/logs/reservation.log then it created a log file in our specified path. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the following in application.properties

```
logging.file = logFileName.log
```

use the below one

```
logging.file.name= appLogName.log
```

Check the Screenshot for your reference.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
logging.file.path=/home/log/
logging.file.name=/home/log/agricom.log
```

mention the path with filename in "logging.file.name".
then it should work fine.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Is this answer really different from https://stackoverflow.com/a/66728794/?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Spring Boot then you can directly **add following properties in application.properties** file to set logging level, 
customize logging pattern and to store logs in the external file.

These are different logging levels and its order from minimum << maximum.

**OFF << FATAL << ERROR << WARN << INFO << DEBUG << TRACE << ALL**

```
# To set logs level as per your need.
logging.level.org.springframework = debug
logging.level.tech.hardik = trace

# To store logs to external file
# Here use strictly forward "/" slash for both Windows, Linux or any other os, otherwise, your logs it won't work.      
logging.file=D:/spring_app_log_file.log

# To customize logging pattern.
logging.pattern.file= "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n"
```

**Please pass through this link to customize your logs more vividly.**

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issues, since i just copied the path as windows(uses "\" in path) provide.

Fixed just by changing : back slash ("\") to forward slash ("/") in path.

Note: Strictly forward slash ("/") should be used in path, OS is not the constraint.

ex:- logging.file.name=D:/Logs/server.log

Answer (score 0):

I run my spring boot service using command line argument which works fine. All the spring boot console log writes to the file. I don't have any logging configured in my `application.properties` file. Spring boot version: `2.0.5.RELEASE`

In windows:

```
java -jar target\microservice-0.0.1.jar --logging.file=C:\\logs\\microservice.log
```

In Linux

```
java -jar target\microservice-0.0.1.jar --logging.file=\var\log\microservice.log
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I pasted some typical config and somehow most probably messed my logging pattern (logging.pattern.file)

Commenting it out solved my own issue (file was created, but nothing was written in it, even though there was console output and root logging level was set to DEBUG) - no errors were given otherwise.

[edit] In other case (I always seem to bump into this problem), I was referencing a JAR file with classes stripped from a web application (WAR), which contained a logback.xml, not to mention AppInitializer - I suspect AppInitializer wouldn't be a problem, since it has a completely different package name and shouldn't be scanned by Spring auto config.. but logback.xml was being detected, I guess, in the classpath, and messed everything completely. I knew it was a hack to reference a WAR, but I was hoping for a quick fix - fixing that, breaking something else. [Mani's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54722690/57033) is related.

Answer (score 0):

For Springboot 2.4.2, Below Application.yml configurations works :

```
logging:
    file:
        name: logpath
```

Answer (score 0):

my problem was that the file is not getting created automatically, and even when i create it in the project root folder, it does not being written into, so eventually, i tried creating a folder and a file inside it `logs/logfile.lo` and setting `logging.file.name=scripts/logfile.log` and the application.proprieties file and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but

```
logging.file.path=../tmp
```

does not work. It is ignored.

only this works

```
logging.file.name=../tmp/regular-encourager-quotes.log
```

Spring Boot starter is 2.7.5

Java 17

Answer (score 0):

For application.yml below mentioned configurations worked for me:

```
    logging:
      file.name: logs/dev_app.log
```