# How to set logging.path for spring-boot apps?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

`spring-boot` provides several `logging.*` settings that can be applied in `application.properties`, like:

```
logging.level.=DEBUG
logging.file=myfile.log
logging.path=d:/logs/
```

Problem: `myfile.log` is generated, BUT inside the classpath! Why isn't spring taking my absolute path into account?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66728794/1691723). The accepted answer is outdated for higher versions of spring boot.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-file-output) states

> By default, Spring Boot will only log to the console and will not
>   write log files. If you want to write log files in addition to the
>   console output you need to set a logging.file or logging.path property
>   (for example in your application.properties).

and then describes how the `logging.file` and `logging.path` properties work. You should only set one.

If `logging.file` is set, it will write to that specific file. The documentation states

> Names can be an exact location or relative to the current directory.

So you're likely writing to your current directory, which happens to be the same as your classpath.

If you set `logging.path`, Spring Boot

> Writes `spring.log` to the specified directory. Names can be an exact location or relative to the current directory.

Check that your current directory isn't your classpath, if you don't want them to mix, and adapt one of the `logging.file` and `logging.path` accordingly.

Comment: Because it is what the documentation indicates :
`Writes to the specified log file. Names can be an exact location or relative to the current directory.` 
Read here :http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html You have a matrix and it doesn't mix the two properties @Sotirios Delimanolis

Answer (score 9):

for Spring boot v2.3.4 and above for sure:
it is **NOT** logging.file=.... ,
it is logging.file.**name**=....

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this is still needed, but you can set the absolute path with following code according to your example

```
logging.path=D:\logs\logfile.txt
```

You can alter the filename and the path like this. If the folder doesn't exist it gets created. On Windows you have to work with \ as seperator, while on Linux and Mac you need / as seperator.

REMEMBER: You cannot have logging.file AND logging.path in your properties together. It is either .file OR .path ... in your case the path.

Tested 2 Minutes before posting

Answer (score 5):

For spring-boot version 2.3.x and above:

```sh
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    my.app: INFO
  file:
    path: './logs/${spring.application.name}'
    name: ${logging.file.path}/my-app.log
```

`logging.file.name` :Log file name (for instance, `myapp.log`). Names can be an exact location or relative to the current directory.

`logging.file.path`: Location of the log file. For instance, `/var/log`.

Reference: [Spring-Boot Core Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#core-properties)

Answer (score 3):

You can also have this configuration on your `app.properties`. Thats how it is working in one of my projects.

```
logging.path=../logs

logging.file=${logging.path}/fileName.log
```

So, you can have both properties and one refers to the other.

Answer (score 0):

I have set `logging.file=C:/usr/local/tomcat/logs/hib.log` in the `application.properties` and the setting like below in class

```
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ChargeMasterController.class);

logger.info("Total time taken for  is ---------------------------" + time  + " ms");
```

Logs are getting printed fine in the path mentioned as logging.file.

Now I want to print my logs in 2 different files for 2 different classes(In same package), how can I set 2 logging.file in application.properties