# How to set absolute logdir in spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-boot

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html

According to the docs above, I could set the logpath and filename as follows.

`logging.file=/var/log/mylog.log`.

BUT: I see the logging to console, but the logfile is never writter (nowhere on the filesystem!).

When I change the property as follows:

`logging.file=var/log/mylog.log`.
Then I'm getting the log in `classpathroot/var/log/mylog.log`.

Question: why is it working under the classpath root, but not in `/var/log`?

Comment: Are you using both logging.file and logging.path or just logging.file ? I ask the question as I had answered you here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/40913904/270371 about it.

Comment: I'm only using `logging.file`.

Comment: This looks fine. Don't have you an access  permission issue? Check it and try another path where you are sure that you have rights on it.

Comment: Man, you're right. Folder permission on `/log` is `root syslog`. What could I do about it?

Comment: sorry for the wrong information regarding the path. I misread it. Regarding the permissions, its a classic. Couple of things regarding this. If you are running this in your system, then you can change the permissions on that folder using `chmod` or if you are running it on some server, you can add the user with which you run this application to a group and give this group permission to write to it

Answer (score 0):

use `logging.path=/var/log/mylog.log` as indicated here
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html  section 26.3

Comment: Doesn't work either... and according to docs this should work with `logging.file`: "Writes to the specified log file. Names can be **an exact location** or relative to the current directory."

Comment: @pvpkiran What you say is in contradiction with the doc. You should not specify the file in the path when you use logging.path. It is only to specify the **specific directory**

Comment: Please read the docs again. Using `logging.path` can only specify the path, and **not** the filename. `logging.file` can both.

Answer (score 0):

If you use relative path in the value of `logging.file`, it will save log in under current directory. As it is mentioned in the section.

> Writes to the specified log file. Names can be an exact location or relative to the current directory.

But if you provide absolute path in the value. Then there is no problem at all. But i think in your case you had put a directory which is not permitted to write file by the user you were trying to run the application.

> Better to provide a directory which having permission to write file or give the permission to the application user (which will run application) to write file in the given directory.